# Filtering a table of array data from a child component

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component

I'm migrating one of my old PHP/jquery single-page applications to VueJS/Webpack in an effort to get comfortable using the latter.  It's a simple table that gets its data from a JSON API and uses filter controls (that are in their own component).  Everything is working except I'm trying to filter my table using the controls in my child component.  I've set up a prop for the array I use as a data source for my table.

My `App.vue` template looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <fan-modals v-bind:fans="fans"></fan-modals>

      <div class="container">
          <filter-controls v-bind:fans="fans"></filter-controls>
          <fans v-bind:fans="fans"></fans>
      </div>  <!-- end #container -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import FilterControls from './components/FilterControls.vue';
  import Fans from './components/Fans.vue';
  import FanModals from './components/FanModals.vue';


  export default {
    name: 'app',
    data: function() {
      return {
        fansUrl: 'example.com',
        fans: []
      }
    },
    components: {
      filterControls: FilterControls,
      fans: Fans,
      fanModals: FanModals
    },
    methods: {
        getFans: function (data) {
            var self = this;
            $.getJSON(self.fansUrl, function(data){
                self.fans = data;
            });
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getFans();
    }
}
</script>
```

I'm trying to reuse my refactored jquery script I used in my old app in a function in my `<FilterControls>` component.  Here's the script section of my `<FilterControls>` child component:

```
<script>
    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {                
                voltageArray: [],
                rpmArray: [],
                noiseLevelArray: [],

                selectedVoltage: 'Voltage',
                selectedRPM: 'Max RPM',
                selectedNoiseLevel: 'Max dBA',

                selectedImpellerSize: '',
                selectedCageSize: '',
                selectedPhase: '',
                selectedFrequency: '',
                secondVoltage: ''
            }
        },
        props: {
            fans: {
                type: Array
            }
        },
        watch: {
            fans(value) {
                this.populateControls(value);
            }
        },
        methods: {
            populateControls(fans) {

                //create emtpy arrays for dropdowns
                var voltage = [];
                var rpm = [];
                var noiseLevel = [];

                //for each fan in fans, get voltages, rpm and noiseLevel values and add them to the empty arrays
                $.each(fans, function(index, value) {
                    voltage.push(fans[index].voltage);
                    rpm.push(fans[index].rpm);
                    noiseLevel.push(fans[index].noise_level);
                });

                //deduplicate and sort arrays
                this.voltageArray = $.unique(voltage).sort();
                this.rpmArray = $.unique(rpm).sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
                this.noiseLevelArray = $.unique(noiseLevel).sort();

            },
             filterFans(fans) {
                var filtered = $.grep(fans, function(fan) {
                   if (this.selectedVoltage === "208-240++") { var secondVoltage = "230"; };

                    return  (selectedImpellerSize === ''    || fan.diameter === selectedImpellerSize);// &&
                            (selectedCageSize === ''            || fan.cage_diameter === selectedCageSize) &&
                            (selectedPhase === ''               || fan.phases === selectedPhase) &&
                            (selectedFrequency === ''           || fan.frequency === selectedFrequency) &&
                            (selectedRPM === 'Max RPM'          || fan.rpm  <= parseInt(selectedRPM)) && 
                            (selectedNoiseLevel === 'Max dBA'   || fan.noise_level <= selectedNoiseLevel) &&
                            (selectedVoltage === 'Voltage'      || fan.voltage === selectedVoltage || fan.voltage === (jQuery.isEmptyObject(secondVoltage) ? selectedVoltage : secondVoltage));
                });

                fans = filtered;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The `populateControls()` method fills my dropdowns with possible values to filter with.  I'm trying to use the `filterFans()` method to filter my `fans` array used to populate my table.  When I attach this method to a  button click I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

It's referencing the line that starts `var filtered = $.grep(fans, function(fan)` so I'm guessing it's having problems iterating through my `fans` array.

I know there's a better way to do this but I'm very new to VueJS.  Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: use `this.fans` in each call to that variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is likely in your usage of the button's event-handler binding. For example, you might have this:

```
<button @click="filterFans()">Filter fans</button>
```

The problem there is the missing function argument (i.e., `fans`) that `filterFans` requires. `$.grep` tries to read `fans.length`, resulting in the error you saw.

You can fix this by either updating the handler in the template:

```
<button @click="filterFans(fans)">Filter fans</button>
```

Or updating `filterFans` to read `this.fans` directly:

```
filterFans() {
  const filtered = $.grep(this.fans, /* ... */);
}
```